# How to structure a module as to deploy separately

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-module

I had a request from my client to deploy a module alone to server. In my app I have multiple module. according to client requirement I need to keep all of modules as a separate application, so each of them can be deployed separately without other modules dependent.

so client can maintain and use it each of the modules when those completed, without waiting for hole app completion.

any one help me here to understand the requirement and how to handle this scenario? I could not find any useful source in the web.

I use `ngrx/store` with `reducer` separately for each of modules for data handling.

Comment: No, you can not replace modules compiled into a webpack. I don't think you can even replace lazy loaded modules and I wouldn't even try. You should look into "micro front-end architecture". Google it. It's where you break up an application into separate web components (not Angular components).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name for your request its `Microservices`. this aprroach apply to any app in any lenguage. but you need to treat each module as a different application and make changes to your server infraestructure (ngnx, apache, dns, etcc...). Angular modules it's to internally modularize your application but its the same application and need be transpiledd all together for keep references to another js files.